# How to check whether the form or value is set or not?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm creating a jsp form, once they submitted in the servlet i have to check whether the form is set or not. In PHP i use to check with the ISSET function same like how i can do it in Servlet??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In servlets you can check using getParameter method of Request Object

```
if(Request.getParameter("Submit")!=null)
{
     ...
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! And i want my database connection  to maintain in a common place so that i can utilize in all the pages. Whether i can have my connection string in the DD or any other better way is there?

Comment: Better create a class with methods defining the basic CRUD operations.Connection string, you can keep in an XML file as we do in .net.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! Here the xml file is nothing but the DD. SO i can keep it there. I think soo..

Answer (score 10):

Another (in my sense more expressive) construct would be

```
request.getParameterMap().containsKey("paramname")
```

as shown [here](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-check-if-parameter-is-exists-in-servlet-request/)

Answer (score 7):

Servlet's [`request.getParameter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) is used to return the value of a request parameter passed as query string and posted data which is encoded in the body of request.

This method is provided by the interface [`ServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) which returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the parameter does not exist. The method `request.getParameter()` retrieves the passed parameters and displays the value of the parameters on the browser.

Servlet equivalent of PHP `isset($_REQUEST['paramname'])` is

```
if (request.getParameter("paramname") != null) { 
    // Parameter is set.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (request.getParameter("paramname") != "")) { 
    // Parameter is set.
}
```

May solve your issue.